# Workflow email not sending to secondary domain users

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have two types of domain users in my sharepoint 2013 site. My problem is: Only one type of domain users get the workflow generated emails but the other type doesn't. Both domain users are configured correctly from SMTP server end. Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a reference to this thread: [SharePoint 2016 - workflow is not sending emails to SharePoint users/ groups](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5864127f-42a6-4941-8c26-d2dbf99b04d3/sharepoint-2016-workflow-is-not-sending-emails-to-sharepoint-users-groups?forum=SP2016). In this case, the issue was caused by user profile synchronization and was solved by running `stsadm -o sync` couple of times in SharePoint Management Shell.

Hope this may help.