# User Profile Synchronization service re-provision

Tags: sharepoint-server, userprofile-sync

User profile synchronization service stuck on status 'starting' in our SharePoint 2013 farm. It causes many issues. One of those issues are:
[Secondary domain users are not getting workflow generated emails](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296662/workflow-email-not-sending-to-secondary-domain-users)
We tried to sync the service by running `stsadm -o sync` but it didn't work. Now, we want to re-provision the User Profile Synchronization service. If we do that, what are the challenges we might face? Will there be any complex issues? Need expert's opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have customization on user profile sync, re-provision is no harm. What UPS do is simply copying the user data from AD to SharePoint's user profile database. As you can see, rebuild the database and re-copying again is no harm.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no negative impact on the SharePoint farm.

And you could use below PowerShell to stop User Profile Synchronization service then restart it.

```
$Service = Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Synchronization Service"}  
$Service.Unprovision()
```